# Laravel 5.2 : How to follow DRY in same rightJoin

Tags: laravel

I have this 4 right join, the difference is in where `harga_sewa.description`.

```
public function method_controller(Request $request, $id){
$dasar = Vehicle::rightJoin('harga_sewa', function ($join){
        $join->on('vehicles.car_class_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.car_class_id');
        $join->on('vehicles.zone_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.zone_id');
    })
    ->select('vehicles.license_plate', 'harga_sewa.value')
    ->where('harga_sewa.description', 'dasar')
    ->where('vehicles.id', $id)
    ->first();

    $luar_kota = Vehicle::rightJoin('harga_sewa', function ($join){
        $join->on('vehicles.car_class_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.car_class_id');
        $join->on('vehicles.zone_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.zone_id');
    })
    ->select('vehicles.license_plate', 'harga_sewa.value')
    ->where('harga_sewa.description', 'luar kota')
    ->where('vehicles.id', $id)
    ->first();

    $overtime = Vehicle::rightJoin('harga_sewa', function ($join) {
        $join->on('vehicles.car_class_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.car_class_id');
        $join->on('vehicles.zone_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.zone_id');
    })
    ->select('vehicles.license_plate', 'harga_sewa.value')
    ->where('harga_sewa.description', 'overtime')
    ->where('vehicles.id', $id)
    ->first();

    $sopir = Vehicle::rightJoin('harga_sewa', function ($join) {
        $join->on('vehicles.car_class_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.car_class_id');
        $join->on('vehicles.zone_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.zone_id');
    })
    ->select('vehicles.license_plate', 'harga_sewa.value')
    ->where('harga_sewa.description', 'sopir')
    ->where('vehicles.id', $id)
    ->first();

    //get the value of each right join
    $dasar = $dasar->value;
    $luar_kota = $luar_kota->value;
    $overtime = $overtime->value;
    $sopir = $sopir->value;
}
```

I think this is ugly code, how should to follow DRY principle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a scope in you `Vehicle` class

```
public function scopeHargaSewa($query)
    {
        return $query->rightJoin('harga_sewa', function ($join) {
            $join->on('vehicles.zone_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.zone_id');
            $join->on('vehicles.car_class_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.car_class_id');
        });
    }
```

Then convert this

```
$dasar = Vehicle::rightJoin('harga_sewa', function ($join){
        $join->on('vehicles.car_class_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.car_class_id');
        $join->on('vehicles.zone_id', '=', 'harga_sewa.zone_id');
    })
    ->select('vehicles.license_plate', 'harga_sewa.value')
    ->where('harga_sewa.description', 'dasar')
    ->where('vehicles.id', $id)
    ->first();
```

to

```
$dasar = Vehicle::hargaSewa()
    ->select('vehicles.license_plate', 'harga_sewa.value')
    ->where('harga_sewa.description', 'dasar')
    ->where('vehicles.id', $id)
    ->first();
```

same goes for other ones.